# Javascript: instantiation of a variable inside an anonymous function

Tags: javascript, function, websocket, scope, anonymous

I'm a bit stuck :/ 
I don't know how to initialize a variable inside an anonymous function, called when the websocket receives a message from the server. 
Is there a way to use the received the message received outside the function? There is a way to do that:

```
// Very simplified code:
var x;
socket.onmessage = function (e) { 
    x = messageReceived; 
}
console.log(x) // print the message received.
```

I hope somebody can help me :)

Comment: Your attempt to `console.log` it is happening before the request completes; the former is synchronous while the latter is asynchronous. You need to use callbacks any time you want to use data returned by an asynchronous request.